# Синонимизировать и объединить [rest] и [restapi]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать и объединить [rest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) (375 вопросов) и [restapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi) (167 вопросов).

По [rest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) больше вопросов, да и на SOen она основная. Предлагаю её сделать основной и у нас.

Comment: Кажется, был какой-то вопрос на Мете, где решили, что [имя] и [имя-api] объединять не стоит.

Comment: @älёxölüt не припоминаю такого. Но добавил ещё один вариант для голосования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделать основной меткой [rest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) и синонимизировать к ней [restapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi).

Answer (score 0):

Сделать основной меткой [restapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restapi) и синонимизировать к ней [rest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest).

Answer (score 0):

Оставить как есть, ничего не объединять и не синонимизировать.